# How to edit blockquote image

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE Advanced, to show more options to edit text.
When I use the `blockquote`, an image appear, like this:

[image]

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add_editor_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) to override the default styles with your custom ones. Like this:

```
function wpse158918_override_default_tinymce_styles() {  
    add_editor_style( 'your-editor-styles.css' );
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse158918_override_default_tinymce_styles' );
```

The code would go into your `functions.php`, the path to the stylesheet is relative to the directory of your current theme. If you are not doing this from your theme, but a plugin, then use the [`mce_css`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_css) filter. Example from codex page:

```
function plugin_mce_css( $mce_css ) {
    if ( ! empty( $mce_css ) )
        $mce_css .= ',';

    $mce_css .= plugins_url( 'editor.css', __FILE__ );

    return $mce_css;
}
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'plugin_mce_css' );
```